# Jersey POST operation with PathParam and JSON Object

Tags: post, jersey

By design, GET operation should be used only for read Only operation. Howeevre,i am looking for a plausible way of implementaion of following.Implement a POST operation that can be called as it is mentioned below

POST /my-store/order/D : where D is the day the customer place an order

Request: POST /my-store/order/14
    {
        "customer" : "XYZ",
        "order" : {
            "item1" : 2
        }
    }

I tried implementing using below function

```
@Path("/D")
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response submitOrder(@PathParam("D") int elapsedDays, @Context UriInfo     uriInfo,     Order orderInfo){
..........
}
```

But the above implementation does not seem to working. When I try to test the implementation using MyEclipse REST explorer ,it does not offer option to pass in Order object but allow 'D' parameter only. However, if @PathParam and @Path is removed then it works perfectly fine i.e. allows to consume JSON Order object.

But,the requirement is to pass the days as Path parameter and Order object as JSON input in POST request.

Looking for suggestion on implementation approach and design approach.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your path should be configured like this:

```
@Path("/{D}")
```

I assume your extended ellipses means you have some method parameter that represents the deserialization of your order.

Comment: Thanks Vidya. As I triy with @Path("/{D}") option. MyEclipse REST explorer stops asking for option to enter JSON object and just allows to enter Method parameter.